# Alert when txt file is updated in folder

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, filemtime

I'm looking for guidance on a question I can barely grasp as is. I have the content of a .txt file loaded through `readfile('stories/'.$sessionid.'.txt');` in PHP. Any user can add text to the .txt file through POST, and I would like for other users with that page open to become notified of (and updated to) the recent file change – whilst the user who did the update doesn't receive an notification about his own update.

I've been having a hard time finding relevant information, since I'm not sure about what I should search for – or even method of approach for that matter (jQuery, AJAX, PHP?). I read something about `filemtime` but I don't know how to apply that in this case. I mainly work with front-end, thus I'm not that experienced with this kind of challenges. I kind of found a solution, but it alerts any file-changes all the time, and could possibly put strain on the server (in worst case senario) I think?

```
var previous = "";

setInterval(function() {
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (ajax.readyState == 4) {
           if (ajax.responseText != previous) {
              alert("file changed!");
              previous = ajax.responseText;
            }
        }
    };
    ajax.open("POST", "stories/<?php echo($sessionid) ?>.txt", true); //Use POST to avoid caching
    ajax.send();
}, 1000);
```

Is there a way to work and develop this code or where should I begin to look and work with? I really don't have a clue since I've never done anything like this before. Any pointers towards relevant keywords, methods, or tutorials I can search for and use would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can do this, but I'd suggest at this point that you hook up a light database and use a message queue instead of constantly checking a file for updates. My personal recommendation would be Redis, it's lightweight and relatively simple for this kind of task.

Answer (score 0):

If you are finding a way to let multiple users edit a file in realtime, then you can use [web sockets](http://socket.io/). `socket.io` is a library that lets you send messages bidirectionally between a server and all the clients connected to it through web sockets.

In your case, once an edit has been made to the txt file, you can broadcast a message to all the connected clients informing them about the change.

Its as simple as `socket.broadcast.emit('File Edited')`, you can either send the new contents over the socket itself or do an ajax query on receiving this socket message.